# How can I save dataset to the correct HDF5 group?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am running a script that iterates through a folder and creates a set of groups to replicate the directory in a HDF5 file. I am then going through the files and adding the data from the files to HDF5 datasets. However, I am looking to save the datasets into the correct groups but unsure how?

```
#Development Script Save files in groups
#Create HDF5 File name
TestFilename = 'N:/TestingPyhonHDF5/progress/automation/GroupTesting.h5'
#Set target directory to extract data 
TargetFolder = 'N:\Measurements\T2+\Rx-BB001'
# giving file extensions
bin = ('.bin')
csv = ('.CSV')
tmp = ('.tmp')
head = ('.head')
ext = ('.bin', '.head', '.tmp', '.CSV')

# Create HDF5 Strucutre
with h5py.File(TestFilename,'w') as tf:
    for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(TargetFolder, topdown=True):
        #print(f'ROOT: {root}')
        # for Windows, modify root: remove drive letter and replace backslashes:
        grp_name = root[2:].replace( '\\', '/')
        #print(f'grp_name: {grp_name}\n')
        tf.create_group(grp_name)

#Open HDF5 file
with h5py.File(TestFilename,'a') as tfile:
#Iterate files to send to HDF5 file
    for path, dirc, files in os.walk(TargetFolder):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(bin):
                # Create a dtype with the binary data format and the desired column names
                filePath = os.path.join(path, file)
                dt = np.dtype('B')
                data = np.fromfile(filePath, dtype=dt)
                df = pd.DataFrame(data)

                #Save as csv
                savetxt('TempData.csv', df, delimiter=',')

                #Read bin to HDF5
                dfBIN = pd.read_csv('TempData.csv')  
                tfile.create_dataset(grp_name/file, data=dfBIN) #put data in hdf file
                #add attrs
                os.remove("TempData.csv")
            else:
                continue
```

Currently the code shows error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [51], line 39
     37 #Read bin to HDF5
     38 dfBIN = pd.read_csv('TempData.csv')  
---> 39 tfile.create_dataset(grp_name/file, data=dfBIN) #put data in hdf file
     40 #add attrs
     41 os.remove("TempData.csv")

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` only works to join [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) objects and you have strings.

Just do

```
f"{grp_name}/{file}"
```

or

```
posixpath.join(grp_name, file)
```

(`posixpath` to ensure forward slashes no matter which platform you're on)

You will also naturally need to do the same `grp_name` determination in the second loop:

```
grp_name = path[2:].replace('\\', '/')
```

Otherwise you're using the last value of `grp_name` from the earlier loop.

All in all, you may just want to go for a single loop. Since I don't know if h5py ignores attempting to (re)create a group that already exists, I added a set that keeps track of paths already created. Also, the intermediate CSV file seemed quite extraneous.

```
import os
import posixpath
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import h5py

TestFilename = "N:/TestingPyhonHDF5/progress/automation/GroupTesting.h5"
TargetFolder = "N:\Measurements\T2+\Rx-BB001"

groups_created = set()

with h5py.File(TestFilename, "a") as tfile:
    for path, dirc, files in os.walk(TargetFolder):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".bin"):
                grp_name = path[2:].replace("\\", "/")
                if grp_name not in groups_created:
                    tfile.create_group(grp_name)
                    groups_created.add(grp_name)
                # Create a dtype with the binary data format and the desired column names
                filePath = os.path.join(path, file)
                dt = np.dtype("B")
                data = np.fromfile(filePath, dtype=dt)
                df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                tfile.create_dataset(posixpath.join(grp_name, file), data=df)
```

Comment: This saves all the data to just the final group created, but I am looking to try save the datasets to the matching group. So when I have the files on my pc directory I am trying to replicate the structure in HDF5 so the files will be in the same group as the file name of my local directory

Comment: @AndrewLittle Right. Please see my edit.